# How to collect exception from visual studio debugger?

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I was wondering how can I get an exception details encountered by VS 2012 debugger? The exception details will be used by a plugin installed within the IDE.

Comment: Very vague.  And doomed to fail, a .NET exception and a C++ exception and a SEH exception have little in common.  You get a exception type, a name, an exception code and a description, that's all.

Comment: well, I am looking for a .net c# exception. Is there way to get that?

Answer (score 1):

[DebuggerEvents.OnExceptionThrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debuggerevents_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from dte.Events.DebuggerEvents provides [ExceptionType, Name, Code, Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dispdebuggerevents_onexceptionthrowneventhandler%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for an exception thrown.